# python - transforming list of unnamed JSON dictionaries with non-unique key-value pairs into single dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, transform

Is have a webhook returning a SOAP XML event details which I'm converting to JSON in a first step. The resulting (partial) snippet looks like this:

```js
"param": [
                {
                  "name": "processStepId",
                  "value": ""
                },
                {
                  "name": "processVariantName",
                  "value": "Default Onboarding Process"
                },
                {
                  "name": "personUuid",
                  "value": "330790C275C5423DAB551676247FC935"
                },
                {
                  "name": "onbStableId",
                  "value": "48E7ABAA133F4370ABBD8837C9E3CD7F"
                },
                {
                  "name": "personIdExternal",
                  "value": 4890
                }
          ]
```

What is this type of structure called, where it's two pairs and where the first key-value pair lists the key-name and the second one list the key-value? I understand that this structure might be helpful when different events return different sets of parameters. In this case the parameters returned will be the same every time.

Is it possible to transform this into a standardized dictionary using some sort of loop in python? I'm hoping to be able to get much tighter and addressable event alerts from this webhook like this:

```js
{
  "processStepId" : "" ,
  "processVariantName" : "Default Onboarding Process" , 
  "personUuid" : "330790C275C5423DAB551676247FC935" , 
  "onbStableId" : "48E7ABAA133F4370ABBD8837C9E3CD7F" , 
  "personIdExternal" : "4890"
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
json_object = { "param": [
                {
                  "name": "processStepId",
                  "value": ""
                },
                {
                  "name": "processVariantName",
                  "value": "Default Onboarding Process"
                },
                {
                  "name": "personUuid",
                  "value": "330790C275C5423DAB551676247FC935"
                },
                {
                  "name": "onbStableId",
                  "value": "48E7ABAA133F4370ABBD8837C9E3CD7F"
                },
                {
                  "name": "personIdExternal",
                  "value": 4890
                }
          ]
}

def convert(obj):
    new_obj = {}

    for item in obj['param']:
        new_obj[item['name']] = str(item['value'])

    return new_obj

print(convert(json_object))

# output
{
 'processStepId': '', 
 'processVariantName': 'Default Onboarding Process',
 'personUuid': '330790C275C5423DAB551676247FC935',
 'onbStableId': '48E7ABAA133F4370ABBD8837C9E3CD7F',
 'personIdExternal': '4890'
 }
```

You may need to edit `convert` if you have a different input schema